# How to make faster the page loading using partial views in Sinatra

Tags: jquery, sinatra

I am really stuck since some days to find out a solution to this problem: when loading the page it takes to much time loading because there are some parts that is loading a `select option` with thousands entries.

I would like to stop loading it initially when the page is called and allowing the select option when the user clicks for example on the `+` sign.

Code:

```
<form action="/example" method="get">
 <select>
   <% session[:var].map(&:to_i).sort.each do |var| %>
     <option><%= var.to_s.force_encoding('UTF-8') %></option>
   <%end%>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="+" />
</form>
```

How can I avoid loading the `<select>` part initially? or is there any better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after struggling for some days I found a solution using partials.

The first partial when the page loads is only the `+`, that means that the `select option` is not loaded. Only when the user requires it by clicking.

```
<div class="delegate">
  <%= erb_partial :partial_empty %>
</div>
```

In this `partial_empty` is something like this:

```
<span class="empty">+</span>
```

Using jquery I created some code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".empty").click(function(){   
    $('#partial_with_select_options).load(encodeURI("URL to controller"));             
  });  
});
```

I am sending some variables to the controller to be able to fill out my `select option`.

So in this way I avoided loading the whole `select options` for each row in my table and therefore accelerating or making faster the loading process of the page.